# After cropping tiff its size increases almost two times

Tags: linux, images, conversion, imagemagick

I have a tiff file 2544x3472 and its size is 402960 bytes. After that I cropped it using ImageMagick (Ubuntu):

```
convert "$path" -crop 2544x1850+0x0 -compress JPEG "${PWD}"/output/$filename
```

and now its size is 762374 bytes. Why and how to decrease its size?

Original file info:

```
Format: TIFF (Tagged Image File Format)
Class: DirectClass
Geometry: 2544x3472+0+0
Resolution: 300x300
Print size: 8.48x11.5733
Units: PixelsPerInch
Type: TrueColor
Base type: TrueColor
Endianess: MSB
Colorspace: sRGB
Depth: 8-bit
Channel depth:
red: 8-bit
green: 8-bit
blue: 8-bit
Channel statistics:
Red:
min: 11 (0.0431373)
max: 255 (1)
mean: 245.305 (0.961982)
standard deviation: 40.5159 (0.158886)
kurtosis: 16.454
skewness: -4.21124
Green:
min: 13 (0.0509804)
max: 255 (1)
mean: 246.888 (0.968189)
standard deviation: 36.9046 (0.144724)
kurtosis: 22.0061
skewness: -4.79686
Blue:
min: 17 (0.0666667)
max: 255 (1)
mean: 248.162 (0.973183)
standard deviation: 35.1016 (0.137653)
kurtosis: 26.3384
skewness: -5.26587
Image statistics:
Overall:
min: 11 (0.0431373)
max: 255 (1)
mean: 246.785 (0.967785)
standard deviation: 37.5749 (0.147352)
kurtosis: 21.027
skewness: -4.71691
Rendering intent: Perceptual
Gamma: 0.454545
Chromaticity:
red primary: (0.64,0.33)
green primary: (0.3,0.6)
blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
white point: (0.3127,0.329)
Interlace: None
Background color: white
Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
Matte color: grey74
Transparent color: black
Compose: Over
Page geometry: 2544x3472+0+0
Dispose: Undefined
Iterations: 0
Compression: JPEG
Orientation: TopLeft
Properties:
date:create: 2016-04-21T07:33:25+03:00
date:modify: 2016-04-20T14:54:59+03:00
jpeg:sampling-factor: 2x2
signature: 78c318002a84787caf29b0e49e527d5cc740ce37f95dd60d901f31c0126aef25
tiff:endian: lsb
tiff:photometric: YCBCR
tiff:rows-per-strip: 16
tiff:software: xsane
tiff:timestamp: 2016:04:20 14:54:59
Artifacts:
filename: page0001.tiff
verbose: true
Tainted: False
Filesize: 403KB
Number pixels: 8.833M
Pixels per second: 73.61MB
User time: 0.130u
Elapsed time: 0:01.120
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2014-03-06 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

Final file info:

```
Format: TIFF (Tagged Image File Format)
Class: DirectClass
Geometry: 2544x1850+0+0
Resolution: 300x300
Print size: 8.48x6.16667
Units: PixelsPerInch
Type: TrueColor
Base type: TrueColor
Endianess: MSB
Colorspace: sRGB
Depth: 8-bit
Channel depth:
red: 8-bit
green: 8-bit
blue: 8-bit
Channel statistics:
Red:
min: 5 (0.0196078)
max: 255 (1)
mean: 236.75 (0.928432)
standard deviation: 54.1507 (0.212356)
kurtosis: 6.55873
skewness: -2.85258
Green:
min: 12 (0.0470588)
max: 255 (1)
mean: 239.712 (0.940049)
standard deviation: 49.538 (0.194267)
kurtosis: 9.47418
skewness: -3.30128
Blue:
min: 10 (0.0392157)
max: 255 (1)
mean: 242.064 (0.949272)
standard deviation: 47.2908 (0.185454)
kurtosis: 11.7772
skewness: -3.66424
Image statistics:
Overall:
min: 5 (0.0196078)
max: 255 (1)
mean: 239.509 (0.939251)
standard deviation: 50.4075 (0.197676)
kurtosis: 8.98602
skewness: -3.24651
Rendering intent: Perceptual
Gamma: 0.454545
Chromaticity:
red primary: (0.64,0.33)
green primary: (0.3,0.6)
blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
white point: (0.3127,0.329)
Interlace: None
Background color: white
Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
Matte color: grey74
Transparent color: black
Compose: Over
Page geometry: 2544x1850+0+0
Dispose: Undefined
Iterations: 0
Compression: JPEG
Orientation: TopLeft
Properties:
date:create: 2016-04-21T09:49:12+03:00
date:modify: 2016-04-21T09:49:12+03:00
jpeg:sampling-factor: 2x2
signature: 713fe32fdb33161257f6836e2cc6c6a929be9003ac9c29f6fd12b5995850c084
tiff:document: /home/output/page0001.tiff
tiff:endian: lsb
tiff:photometric: RGB
tiff:rows-per-strip: 16
tiff:software: xsane
tiff:timestamp: 2016:04:20 14:54:59
Artifacts:
filename: page0001.tiff
verbose: true
Tainted: False
Filesize: 762KB
Number pixels: 4.706M
Pixels per second: 52.29MB
User time: 0.090u
Elapsed time: 0:01.089
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2014-03-06 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of specifying the `JPEG` compression type, try using the `Zip` compression type after the `-compress` option to compress the output file more as follows:

```
convert "$path" -crop 2544x1850+0x0 -compress Zip "${PWD}"/output/$filename
```

This resulted in an output .tif file that was approximately 70% of the size of the input .tif file that I used. This suggests to me that there may be something unusual about the .tif file that you used as an example file. Try downloading a different .tif file from the [TIFF Sample Files](https://www.fileformat.info/format/tiff/sample/) webpage and check the original image's width and height before you specify the new values for cropping the image.

**Note:** Using ImageMagick's `-quality` option with my .tif file resulted in no change in the output .tif file's size, regardless of the value of the `-quality` option.

Comment: if I apply Zip compression its size 1,5 MB

Comment: This doesn't happen in my computer in Ubuntu 14.04. I added more information to my answer about what happens when running the command with my tiff file. Perhaps you could upload your tiff file to any photo sharing website and provide a link to it, so I could download it and see what happens if I run the same command with your tiff file.